# Performance of search query bottlenecked 98% by mutual friends despite caching

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, activerecord

So on my social networking website, similar to facebook, my search speed is bottlenecked like 98% by this one part. I want to rank the results based on the number of mutual friends the searching user has, with all of the results (we can assume they are users)

My friends table has 3 columns -

- user_id (person who sends the request)
- friend_id (person who receives the request)
- pending (boolean to indicate if the request was accepted or not)

user_id and friend_id are both foreign keys that reference users.id

Finding friend_ids of a user is simple, it looks like this

```
def friends
  Friend.where(
    '(user_id = :id OR friend_id = :id) AND pending = false',
     id: self.id
  ).pluck(:user_id, :friend_id)
   .flatten
   .uniq
   .reject { |id| id == self.id }
end
```

So, after getting the results that match the search query, ranking the results by mutual friends, requires following steps -

- Get user_ids of all the searching user's friends - Set(A). Above mentioned friends method does this
- Loop over each of the ids in Set(A) -

  - Get user_ids of all the friends of |id| - Set (B). Again, done by friends method
  - Find length of intersection of set A and set B
- Order in descending order of length of intersections for all results

The most expensive operation over here obviously getting friend_ids of of hundreds of users. So I cached the friend_ids of all the users to speed it up. The difference in performance was amazing, but I'm curious if it can be further improved.

I'm wondering if there is a way that I can get friend_ids of all the desired users in a single query, that is efficient. Something like -

```
SELECT user_id, [array of friend_ids of the user with id = user_id]
FROM friends
....
```

Can someone help me write a fast SQL or ActiveRecord query for this?

That way I can store the user_ids of all the search results and their corresponding friend_ids in a hash or some other fast data structure, and then perform the same operation of ranking (that I mentioned above). Since I won't be hitting the cache for thousands of users and their friend_ids, I think it'll speed up the process significantly

Comment: By "cached", do you mean "indexed"?

Comment: No I mean I use a  in-memory data structure store called Redis to cache the friend_ids of a user

Comment: To be clear, the search whose results you are trying to rank this way is a performed on behalf of one user, against one or more unspecified other tables, and its results are other users?

Comment: Do you ensure that user pairs are enrolled at most once in table `friends`?  Including if you reverse `user_id` and `friend_id`?  If not, is the omission intentional?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, the search is performed on behalf of one user, against one table (friends) and its results are other user_ids

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes I do have a rails validation that enforces uniqueness of user_ids in scope of friend_ids in the friends table

Answer (score 1):

Caching your `friends` table in RAM is not a viable approach if you expect your site to grow to large numbers of users, but I'm sure it does great for a smallish number of users.

It is to your advantage to get the most work you can out of the database with as few calls as possible.  It is inefficient to issue large numbers of queries, as the overhead per query as comparatively large.  Moreover, databases are built for the kind of task you're trying to perform.  I think you are doing far too much work on the Ruby side, and you ought to let the database do the kind of work it does best.

You did not give many details, so I decided to start by defining a minimal model DB:

```
create table users (
  user_id int not null primary key,
  nick varchar(32)
  );

create table friends (
  user_id int not null,
  friend_id int not null,
  pending bool,
  primary key (user_id, friend_id),
  foreign key (user_id) references users(user_id),
  foreign key (friend_id) references users(user_id),
  check (user_id < friend_id)
  );
```

The `check` constraint on `friends` avoids the same pair of users being listed in the table in both orders, and of course the PK prevents the same pair from being enrolled multiple times in the same order.  The PK also automatically has a unique index associated with it.

Since I suppose the 'is a friend of' relation is supposed to be logically symmetric, it is convenient to define a view that presents that symmetry:

```
create view friends_symmetric (user_id, friend_id) as (
  select user_id, friend_id from friends where not pending
  union all
  select friend_id, user_id from friends where not pending
  );
```

(If friendship is *not* symmetric then you can drop the check constraint and the view, and use table `friends` in place of `friends_symmetric` in what follows.)

As a model query whose results you want to rank, then, I take this:

```
select * from users where nick like 'Sat%';
```

The objective is to return result rows in descending order of the number of friends each hit has in common with User1, the user on whose behalf the query is run.  You might do that like so:

(**update**: modified this query to filter out duplicate results)

```
select *
from (
    select
      u.*,
      count(mutual.shared_friend_id) over (partition by u.user_id) as num_shared,
      row_number() over (partition by u.user_id) as copy_num
    from 
      users u
      left join (
          select
            f1.friend_id as shared_friend_id,
            f2.friend_id as friend_id
          from friends_symmetric f1
            join friends_symmetric f2
              on f1.friend_id = f2.user_id
          where f1.user_id = ?
            and f2.friend_id != f1.user_id
        ) mutual
        on u.user_id = mutual.friend_id
    where u.nick like 'Sat%'
  ) all_rows
where copy_num = 1
order by num_shared desc
```

where the `?` is a placeholder for a parameter containing the ID of the User1.

---

**Edited to add:**

I have structured this query with window functions instead of an aggregate query with the idea that such a structure will be easier for the query planner to optimize.  Nevertheless, the inline view "mutual" could instead be structured as an aggregate query that computes the number of shared friends that the searching user has with every user that shares at least one friend, and that would permit one level of inline view to be avoided.  If performance of the provided query is or becomes inadequate, then it would be worthwhile to test that variant.

---

There are other ways to approach the problem of performing the sorting in the DB, some of which may perform better, and there may be ways to improve the performance of each by tweaking the database (adding indexes or constraints, modifying table definitions, computing db statistics, ...).

I cannot predict whether that query will outperform what you're doing now, but I assure you that it scales better, and it is easier to maintain.

Comment: Yes that sounds much more scalable than my approach, however, I need the number of mutual friends between the searcher and a search result user also. Also, when I run the query you wrote it gives me repeats of users (maybe you need to GROUP ON somewhere?). Thanks!

Comment: @Satnamxv63, updated to include the number of shared friends in the results.  There is no need for a `group by` clause because I'm using the window function version of `count()`, not the aggregate function version.  You can tell by the inclusion of the `over()` modifier.  I just added the same expression to the select list that the query was already ordering by.

Comment: num_shared works great, but it still shows the same result multiple times and that too at random locations. Can you fix that?

Comment: @Satnamxv63, I'm going to suppose that the query presented duplicate results in exactly those cases where a hit has more than one friend in common with the searcher.  My bad on that.  I have updated the query to avoid that effect, and inserted a comment about an alternative way the query could have been structured.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want a relation of the `User` model whose primary key is `id`, you should be able to join onto a subquery that calculates the number of mutual friends:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def other_users_ordered_by_mutual_friends
    self.class.select("users.*, COALESCE(f.friends_count, 0) AS friends_count").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT all_friends.user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT all_friends.friend_id) AS friends_count FROM (
        SELECT f1.user_id, f1.friend_id FROM friends f1 WHERE f1.pending = false
        UNION ALL
        SELECT f2.friend_id AS user_id, f2.user_id AS friend_id FROM friends f2 WHERE f2.pending = false
      ) all_friends INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT f1.friend_id AS user_id FROM friends f1 WHERE f1.user_id = #{id} AND f1.pending = false
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT f2.user_id FROM friends f2 WHERE f2.friend_id = #{id} AND f2.pending = false
      ) user_friends ON user_friends.user_id = all_friends.friend_id GROUP BY all_friends.user_id
    ) f ON f.user_id = users.id").where.not(id: id).order("friends_count DESC")
  end
end
```

The subquery selects all user IDs with associated friends and inner joins that to another select with all of the current user's friends' IDs. Since it groups by the `user_id` and selects the count, we get the number of mutual friends for each `user_id`. I have not tested this since I don't have any sample data, but it should work.

Since this returns a scope, you can chain other scopes/conditions to the relation:

```
current_user.other_users_ordered_by_mutual_friends.where(attribute1: value1).reorder(:attribute2)
```

The `select` scope as written will also give you access to the field `friends_count` on instances within the relation:

```
<%- current_user.other_users_ordered_by_mutual_friends.each do |user| -%>
  <p>User <%= user.id -%> has <%= user.friends_count -%> mutual friends.</p>
<%- end -%>
```

Comment: I receive "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "f"" on the second line of the query

Comment: It works now, but it gives me only the friends of the user and nothing about the number of mutual friends

Answer (score 0):

John had a great idea with the `friends_symetric` view. With two filtered indexes (one on (friend_id,user_id and the other on (user_id,friend_id) ) it's gonna work great.
However the query can be a bit simpler

```
WITH user_friends AS(
  SELECT user_id, array_agg(friend_id) AS friends
    FROM friends_symmetric
        WHERE user_id = :user_id -- id of our user
    GROUP BY user_id
)
SELECT u.*
       ,array_agg(friend_id) AS shared_friends -- aggregated ids of friends in case they are needed for something
       ,count(*) AS shared_count    
FROM user_friends AS uf     
    JOIN friends_symmetric AS f
        ON f.user_id = ANY(uf.friends) AND f.friend_id = ANY(uf.friends)
    JOIN user
        ON u.user_id = f.user_id
WHERE u.nick LIKE 'Sat%' --nickname of our user's friend
GROUP BY u.user_id
```